# Split content with multiple lines into multiple rows and columns in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, text

I like to know if it is possible to split an entire paragraph contained in a single cell, into multiple columns and paragraphs using formula's in Google sheets. This is what the text in the cell would look like:

```
1 coffeeextradark 240gr

1 milkshake 28Oz

5 chocolatebigones 30 pcs

2 andthelistgoeson 34items
```

And this is how I would like it to be split up into separate cells

```
1 | coffeeextradark  | 35

1 | milkshake        | 28Oz

5 | chocolatebigones | 30 pcs

2 | andthelistgoeson | 34items
```

I found these nice examples how this can be done [using formulas combined with Excel's Text to columns tool](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/splitting-multiline-cell-into-rows-t1755328.html) or [using VBA](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=147965), but can someone help me to do the same using Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the `=SPLIT` function would do what you need. Given that `A1` contains the text `1 coffeeextradark 240gr`, then

```
=SPLIT(A1, " ")
```

<sup>(notice the space between the quotation marks)</sup>

will split the text into three cells:

```
1 | coffeeextradark | 240gr
```

Comment: Awesome formula! I applied it in the following ways: =TRANSPOSE(SPLIT, " ") and = TRANSPOSE(SPLIT, Char(10))

Comment: Cool! Glad it worked for you!